# Create basic server using Docker

Tags: 7

I am trying to work out how to create a Drupal dev environment using Docker.  I am trying to use the Docker containers for Drupal (https://hub.docker.com/r/library/drupal/) and MySQL (https://hub.docker.com/r/library/mysql/) to set up a Drupal server.

I am assuming that I need to link the MySQL container to the Drupal container.  I have created a docker-compose.yml file which seems to run fine on `docker-compose up` (I am using a Mac).

**docker-compose.yml file:**

```
drupal:
  image: drupal
  ports:
   - "8080:80"
  links:
   - db
db:
  image: mysql
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysql
    MYSQL_DATABASE: drupal
    MYSQL_USER: drupal
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: drupal
    MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: yes
```

After docker-composer completes, I can access the Drupal site from my web browser.  The Drupal installation works up to the point where I have to enter the database details.  At this point it fails:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Make sure to put in the "Host" of the MySQL database under "Advanced Configuration" as `db` and not the default `localhost`.

Comment: could note you can also explicitly define the hostname of the mySQL container in your composer.yaml file config, eg hostname: db

https://github.com/4alldigital/drupaldev-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L43

Answer (score 2):

When you link containers in docker compose, you still have to reference the database server in your configuration (in this case as 'db'); your database will be on db:3306.

Have a look at [an example about doing it with Wordpress](https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/).

I suspect you are just not pointing it at the server.

You also set the database user as root, but in your yml that is drupal (which might be another issue).

Answer (score 1):

**1. To get all container names and their ips in just one single command.**

```
docker inspect -f '{{.Name}} - {{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' $(docker ps -aq)
```

**Output:**
/drupal7_drupal_1 - 172.17.0.3
/drupal7_db_1 - 172.17.0.2
**2. Set up Database:**

Database name: drupal
Database username: drupal
Database password: drupal
Host: 172.17.0.2
**docker-compose.yml**

```
drupal:
  image: drupal
  ports:
   - "8080:80"
  links:
   - db
db:
  image: mysql
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: drupal
    MYSQL_DATABASE: drupal
    MYSQL_PORT: 3306
    MYSQL_USER: drupal
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: drupal
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on a dev env for Drupal specifically using Docker and recently open sourced the BETA version with the intention to help others as well as streamline my dev setup : https://www.4alldigital.io/docker-drupal

Supposed to be a single command install and away you go. would love feedback if it helps or hinders... and how it can better server Drupal devs who wanna spend less time on local devOps